# Windows Phone Not Showing Image

Tags: windows-phone-7

In the code below, the image "imgNew" doesn't show on the canvas when I launch the application, all the other images show. It is the fourth one from the bottom :

```xml
<Image Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,656,0,0" Name="imgNew" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/N%26C_new_1.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="imgNew_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" />
```

---

```xml
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Elementals;component/Main/HomeImages/bg_fire_3.png" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Image Height="458" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,154,0,0" Name="imgGrid" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/Grid.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="458" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,171,0,0" Name="LeftTop" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/empty.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="LeftTop_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,171,0,0" Name="MiddleTop" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/empty.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="MiddleTop_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="335,171,0,0" Name="RightTop" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/empty.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="RightTop_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="335,479,0,0" Name="RightBottom" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/empty.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="RightBottom_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,479,0,0" Name="MiddleBottom" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/empty.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="MiddleBottom_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,479,0,0" Name="LeftBottom" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/empty.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="LeftBottom_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="335,325,0,0" Name="RightMiddle" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/empty.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="RightMiddle_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,325,0,0" Name="MiddleMiddle" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/empty.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="MiddleMiddle_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,325,0,0" Name="LeftMiddle" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/empty.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="LeftMiddle_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,46,0,0" Name="lblPlayerX" Text="X Points:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,10,0,0" Name="lblPlayerO" Text="O Points:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Image Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,656,0,0" Name="imgNew" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/N%26C_new_1.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="imgNew_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" />
    <Image Height="178" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,325,0,0" Name="lblX" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/WHo_First_3.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Tap="lblX_Tap" />
    <Image Height="138" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,154,0,0" Name="lblWhosGo" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/WHo_First_2.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420" />
    <Image Height="180" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,325,0,0" Name="lblO" Source="/Elementals;component/NoughtsAndCrosses/NACImages/WHo_First_4.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Tap="lblO_Tap" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it is getting messed up with the HTML encoded character in the filename.  %26 is the same as the ampersand `&`, and that is likely to cause you issues all over.  I'd recommend that you rename the file to something without the special character.

Answer (score 1):

did you set the "Build action" to content for that image? make sure you did